# JSON.stringify is bolding the keys instead of leaving them as quotes

Tags: javascript, html, json

When I load the page on localhost, it first outputs everything, but then after a few seconds the page updates and all the keys are bolded instead of being strings.

This is a problem since I would like to copy the data and save it to a JSON file. I can't do this before hand because I am iterating through an array to save all the data as a JSON object and outputting it to the html.

Also if there is a better way to do this (rather than having to go to the browser to collect the data) this would also be helpful to know.

```
{
JOBS: [
{
symbol: "JOBS",
timestamp: "2013-10-01T00:00:00-04:00",
tradingDay: "2013-10-01",
open: 36.65,
high: 40,
low: 34.34,
close: 38.95,
volume: 56687,
openInterest: null
},
{
symbol: "JOBS",
timestamp: "2014-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
tradingDay: "2014-01-01",
open: 38.585,
high: 43,
low: 34.57,
close: 35.625,
volume: 89786,
openInterest: null
} 
...
```

Comment: Your posted code is the start of a javascript object literal ( it just needs `]}` to complete it). You haven't  mentioned what the page does and also hint it might be an intermediary step to achieve something else. More information about what the context and what is going wrong please.

Comment: Sounds like you have JSONView or some addon like that installed. Do you?